# How to cache popover controllers?

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching

In the apple  [iPad-Specific Controllers guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html) a tip for managing popovers in a application is this:

*Popover controllers can be reused, so cache popover controllers rather than creating new ones from scratch. Popover controllers are very malleable and so you can specify a different view controller and configuration options each time you use them.*

How can I implement this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply by declaring an instance variable/property and storing the reference to the popover controller in that variable. Then, if you need it, check if the property is `nil` and only create a fresh controller when that is the case. Otherwise, use the existing controller that you can reference from the ivar/property.